Hudi Upsert Job keeps failing at distinct step at HoodieJavaRDD.distinct(HoodieJavaRDD.java:157)
Problem Statement:
Running an ETL on a table "Aggregate X Details". When running this on a large dataset i.e. ~30M rows of data we partition our dataset into 50 partitions. But the executors are failing repeatedly at distinct at MapPartitionsRDD step.
HUDI Configuration:
    hoodie.datasource.write.operation: upsert
    hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class: org.apache.hudi.keygen.TimestampBasedKeyGenerator
    hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism: 2
    hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field: timestamp (which is year truncated)
    hoodie.datasource.write.table.type: COPY_ON_WRITE
    hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field: timestamp
    hoodie.index.type: simple

Spark Config:
    spark.executor.instances=0; 
    spark.executor.memory=32g; 
    spark.driver.memory=4g; 
    spark.driver.cores=4; 
    spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=1; 
    spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=5

Environment Description

Amazon EMR Version: emr-6.15.0

Hudi version : 0.14.0-amzn-0

Spark version : 3.4.1-amzn-2

Hive version : 3.1.3

Hadoop version : 3.3.6-amzn-1

Storage (HDFS/S3/GCS..) : S3 (But spark uses HDFS for processing tasks in EMR serverless)

Running on Docker? (yes/no) : No


StackTrace
When running this on a large dataset i.e. ~30M rows of data we partition our dataset into 50 partitions. But the executors are failing repeatedly at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.distinct(JavaRDD.scala:85) org.apache.hudi.data.HoodieJavaRDD.distinct(HoodieJavaRDD.java:157) org.apache.hudi.index.simple.HoodieSimpleIndex.fetchRecordLocationsForAffectedPartitions(HoodieSimpleIndex.java:147) org.apache.hudi.index.simple.HoodieSimpleIndex.tagLocationInternal(HoodieSimpleIndex.java:118) org.apache.hudi.index.simple.HoodieSimpleIndex.tagLocation(HoodieSimpleIndex.java:91) org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.HoodieWriteHelper.tag(HoodieWriteHelper.java:59) org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.HoodieWriteHelper.tag(HoodieWriteHelper.java:41) org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.BaseWriteHelper.write(BaseWriteHelper.java:63) org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.SparkUpsertCommitActionExecutor.execute(SparkUpsertCommitActionExecutor.java:44) org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.upsert(HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.java:114) org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.upsert(HoodieSparkCopyOnWriteTable.java:103) org.apache.hudi.client.SparkRDDWriteClient.upsert(SparkRDDWriteClient.java:142) org.apache.hudi.DataSourceUtils.doWriteOperation(DataSourceUtils.java:224) org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.writeInternal(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:431) org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.write(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:132) org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:150) org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:47) org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75) org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)     org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)

Losing shuffle mapped locations:
    MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 1 to 2600:1f13:d89:d701:c1b3:f3b3:161c:a99e:41804
    24/10/23 10:31:07 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 4.0 (TID 7) ([2600:1f13:d89:d701:c1b3:f3b3:161c:a99e] executor 2): FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=1, mapIndex=-1, mapId=-1, reduceId=1, message=
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 1 partition 1
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.validateStatus(MapOutputTracker.scala:1732)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.$anonfun$convertMapStatuses$11(MapOutputTracker.scala:1679)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.$anonfun$convertMapStatuses$11$adapted(MapOutputTracker.scala:1678)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:1678)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getMapSizesByExecutorIdImpl(MapOutputTracker.scala:1320)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:1282)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager.getReader(SortShuffleManager.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleManager.getReader(ShuffleManager.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleManager.getReader$(ShuffleManager.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager.getReader(SortShuffleManager.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$getOrCompute$1(RDD.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1552)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:563)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:566)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    
    )

Expected behavior
Should be able to parallelize the distinct operation to allow HUDI upsert operation to de-duplicate records for these data rows.

Found out the solution. I was errantly passing in hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism: 2, which was limiting sparks ability to parallelize the distinct operation, limiting execution vectors to 2. Explanation https://hudi.apache.org/docs/configurations/#hoodieupsertshuffleparallelism
